# How to encode union on the subset of fields using Dhall?

Tags: dhall

I'm trying to use Dhall to generate AWS Cloudformation and the first thing I'm trying to encode is [AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html). Which has following the json spec:

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api",
  "Properties" : {
    "ApiKeySelectionExpression" : String,
    "BasePath" : String,
    "Body" : Json,
    "BodyS3Location" : BodyS3Location,
    "CorsConfiguration" : Cors,
    "CredentialsArn" : String,
    "Description" : String,
    "DisableSchemaValidation" : Boolean,
    "FailOnWarnings" : Boolean,
    "Name" : String,
    "ProtocolType" : String,
    "RouteKey" : String,
    "RouteSelectionExpression" : String,
    "Tags" : Json,
    "Target" : String,
    "Version" : String
  }
}
```

The specification has multiple fields but two of them form a union: `BodyS3Location` and `Body`. Mean that either one of them should be present. I'm aware of the support for [dynamic records](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/wiki/Getting-started%3A-Generate-JSON-or-YAML#dynamic-records) but apparently only works for objects with single record. What would be the recommended way to encode this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not generalize well, but for this specific example you can do this:

```
let JSON = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/v12.0.0/JSON/package.dhall

-- These are just placeholders for whatever the real types are
let BodyS3Location = {}

let Cors = {}

let Shared =
      { ApiKeySelectionExpression : Text
      , BasePath : Text
      , CorsConfiguration : Cors
      , CredentialsArn : Text
      , Description : Text
      , DisableSchemaValidation : Bool
      , FailOnWarnings : Bool
      , Name : Text
      , ProtocolType : Text
      , RouteKey : Text
      , RouteSelectionExpression : Text
      , Tags : JSON.Type
      , Target : Text
      , Version : Text
      }

in  < A : Shared //\\ { BodyS3Location : BodyS3Location }
    | B : Shared //\\ { Body : JSON.Type }
    >
```